# How to lock system?

Tags: c#, .net, system

How may I completely lock the system via `C-Sharp` code like the 
[Bundespolizei-Virus](http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Bundespolizei-Ukash-Virus-Manually) does? I´m trying to secure my computer with a little software that locks the system when nothing happens for 5 minutes and only unlocks when the user entered the right password.

It´s not my goal to write an own virus or something like that, it´d just be nice to know how.

I don´t want to lock it as windows does because I want to show my own User Interface.

It´d also be useful when writing a program for public computers where users only should work with this program and have no possibilities to access the operating system in any way.

Comment: Nice try, aspiring virus author

Comment: "It's not my intention to build nuclear wepons. It'd simply be nice to know how. For strictly civilian purpose."

Comment: Password protected screensaver is the answer. No need to write any code, system already ships with the feature you need.

Comment: I want to write an own tool because activating a screensaver with password is too easy. I want to write my own tool for it... And NO I´M NOT A VIRUS PROGRAMMER, why do you always think of the worst?

Comment: If you want to be able to lock the user session in the same way a user would with ctrl-alt-del then Furqan has given you the right answer. If you want to lock the system using something other than user sessions and windows security then that's something that can't be answered easily. At that point your question is basically another 'please can I have teh COdez'.

Comment: try that http://pastebin.com/stqPqr6s - I haven't written it, so ..

Comment: Preventing Ctrl-Alt-Del sounds difficult. You need at least admin privs for that, and perhaps there isn't even an API that can do that.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, just set a screensaver password with a timeout for 5 minutes. That's as secure as you can get.

[Updated]

Ah, you've updated the question. So you don't want the standard windows lock screen? Well it depends on how secure you want it to be. As I said in a comment above, you'll not be able to intercept CTRL+ALT+DEL unless you hook into the security subsystem. You used to be able to do this by writing a custom GINA DLL, but since Vista this is deprecated. Now you need to do this with custom "Credential Providers";

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx

If you don't want to take this route, you could also use "Policy" to lock a machine down to a point, but there's always a way around a user-mode app. If the user can bring up task manager then they can run anything on the box usually.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this piece of code to lock the workstation, using API from **user32.dll**:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool LockWorkStation();
```

**Usage:**

```
bool result = LockWorkStation();
if (result == false)
{
    // An error occured
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

References:

1. [Lock computer using c# in window application](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/337619/Lock-computer-using-csharp-in-window-application)
2. [Lock, Sleep or Hibernate Windows using C#](http://codehill.com/2009/01/lock-sleep-or-hibernate-windows-using-c/)

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't what the OP wants. Sounds like he wants a custom lock screen to me.

Comment: Custom lock screen? Have i missed it?

Comment: I think this is a good answer if you want to do it programmatically. A custom lock screen won't be secure unless you integrate with the security subsystem. Otherwise the SAS (CTRL+ALT+DEL) will always be able to override it - that's the point of it!

Comment: Yeah, I know preventing the CtrlAltDel isn´t that easy but there has to be a way because the virus also did it; the virus was able to completely deny any action the user initiated.